# scipy.optimize.minimize choosing parameters that defy constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, statistics, minimize

I am running scipy.optimize.minimize trying to maximize the likelihood for left-truncated data on a Gompertz distribution. Since the data is left-truncated at `1`, I get this likelihood:

```
# for a single point x_i, the left-truncated log-likelihood is:
#   ln(tau) + tau*(ln(theta) - ln(x_i)) - (theta / x_i) ** tau - ln(x_i) - ln(1 - exp(-(theta / d) ** tau))
def to_minimize(args, data, d=1):
  theta, tau = args
  if tau <= 0 or theta <= 0 or theta / d < 0 or np.exp(-(theta / d) ** tau) >= 1:
    print('ERROR')
  term1 = len(data) * (np.log(tau) + tau * np.log(theta) - np.log(1 - np.exp(-(theta / d) ** tau)))
  term2 = 0
  for x in data:
    term2 += (-(tau + 1) * np.log(x)) - (theta / x) ** tau
  return term1 + term2
```

This will fail in all instances where the `if` statement is true. In other words, `tau` and `theta` have to be strictly positive, and `theta ** tau` must be sufficiently far away from `0` so that `np.exp(-theta ** tau)` is "far enough away" from `1`, since otherwise the logarithm will be undefined.

These are the constraints which I thus defined. I used the notation with a `dict` instead of a `NonlinearConstraints` object since it seems that this methods accepts strict inequality (`np.exp(-x[0] ** x[1])` must be strictly less than `1`). Maybe I have misunderstood the documentation on this.

```
def constraints(x):
  return [1 - np.exp(-(x[0]) ** x[1])]
```

To maximize the likelihood, I minimize the negative likelihood.

```
opt = minimize(lambda args: -to_minimize(args, data),
               x0=np.array((1, 1)), 
               constraints={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraints},
               bounds=np.array([(1e-15, 10), (1e-15, 10)]))
```

As I take it, the two arguments should then never be chosen in a way such that my code fails. Yet, the algorithm tries to move `theta` very close to its lower bound and `tau` very close to its upper bound so that the logarithm becomes undefined.

What makes my code fail?

Comment: It should be noted that I have checked if the problem still occurs if I nudge the bound a little. Even when I use ```[(1 - 1e-10) - np.exp(-(x[0]) ** x[1])]``` in the constraints function, the problem persists.

Comment: Can you provide some `data` to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms of constraints, i.e. `NonlinearConstraint` and `dict` constraints don't support strict inequalities. Typically, one therefore uses `g(x) >= c + Ɛ`  to model the strict inequality `g(x) > c`, where `Ɛ` is a sufficiently small number.

Note also that it is not guaranteed that each iteration lies inside the feasible region. Internally, most of the methods try to bring it back into the feasible region by a simple clipping of the bounds. In cases where this doesn't work, you can try `NonlinearConstraint`s `keep_feasible` option and then use the `trust-constr` method:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint, minimize

def con_fun(x):
    return 1 - np.exp(-(x[0]) ** x[1])

# 1.0e-8 <= con_fun <= np.inf
con = NonlinearConstraint(con_fun, 1.0e-8, np.inf, keep_feasible=True)

x0 = np.array((1., 1.))
bounds = np.array([(1e-5, 10), (1e-5, 10)])

opt = minimize(lambda args: -to_minimize(args, data),
               x0=x0, constraints=(con,),
               bounds=bounds, method="trust-constr")
```

Comment: This is very interesting and I wasn't aware of these details, so thank you. I will try to move forward with the ```keep_feasible``` option and the ```trust-constr``` method.